# Activity - onActivityResult not called

Tags: android, android-intent

I have three activities: a1 -> a2 -> a3

a1 is kind of an intro that loads data and finally calles a2 using `startActivity(a2)`.
a2 is calling a3 using a FloatingActionButton with `a2.this.startActivityForResult(intentForA3, 1);`
a2 overwrites `onActivityResult` - Method, but never get called when a3 is closed via 
  `setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent); finish();`

a2 is using a RecyclerView with an adapter, but the Button is placed directly in a2, so that should not be a problem. But yet closing a3  minimizes all activities. It is still running in background and resuming it shows a1 that quickley "skips" to a2.

This is my manifest:

```
    <activity android:name="de.activity.A1"
        android:label="">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="de.activity.A2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="de.activity.A3"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:parentActivityName="de.activity.A2"
        android:label="">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="de.activity.A2" />
    </activity>
```

My config:

```
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
       applicationId "something here"
       minSdkVersion 15
       targetSdkVersion 24
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
    }
```

**EDIT:**

A2:

```
    public class A2 extends AppCompatActivity {
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent insertIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), A3.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putSerializable("content", importantContent);
                    insertIntent.putExtra("content", b);
                    A2.this.startActivityForResult(insertIntent, 1);
                }
            });

       @Override
       public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
             // Never called
             if (requestCode == 1) {
                   if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                          switch (data.getAction()) {
                             case CMD_SAVE_OBJECT:
                             break;
                          }
                   }
             }
       }
  }
```

A3:

```
    public class A3 extends AppCompatActivity {

       // ...

       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_save_object) {
                readTopicFromView();

                Intent returnIntent = new Intent(CMD_SAVE_OBJECT);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

ANOTHER EDIT:

I have the same problem when I press the "Back"-arrow in the toolbar of a3. Is there a PARENT_ACTIVITY - problem in the manifest that forwards the return to first activity?

Comment: sharing code of a2 and a3 activities will be helpful

Comment: @Anuran Barman: I added the classes

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in set result of activity 3

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "Your message to pass to parent actvity"));
 setResult(1, intent);
 finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the **action** from the intent **data** while you have not put it in the intent from **a3**. Try to put it into the **resultIntent** by **resultIntent.putExtra("ACTION","my_action")** and then sending it to the a2 activity and getting it via **data.getStringExtra("key")** from a2 in **onActivityResult()**

Comment: I added the extra as @Ramees also mentioned. But onActivityResult() is never called. I set a breakpoint, but it is never "reached"

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're using a wrong code:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent(CMD_SAVE_OBJECT);
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

It should be:

```
  Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
  // pass the data, remember the key.
  returnIntent.putExtra("extra", CMD_SAVE_OBJECT);
  // Activity finished ok, return the data
  setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
```

Then, you need to handle the result with:

```
   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

     if (requestCode == 1) {
         if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // In case you're sending an int data.
            // remember to use the same key, which is "extra_object"
            int action = data.getExtras().getInt("extra");
            switch (action) {
              case CMD_SAVE_OBJECT:
                break;
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: I does not seem to make a difference if I pass the action via the constructor of Intent or set it manually or if I don't pass it at all. I tried it. Method onActivityResult is just not called.

Comment: @OtisOttington: try commenting the `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in your manifest.

Comment: No. But when I press the "Back"-arrow in the toolbar I have the same problem. Is there a PARENT_ACTIVITY - problem in the manifest that forwards the return to first activity?

Comment: you can try to commenting it. I never use `android:parentActivityName` attribute, instead I'm using navigator pattern.